# Laravel questions about using One to One relationship between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 **tables** which is **district** and **address**. Suppose these 2 tables have relations between each other. **address** table holds **district** foreign key. The problem is that it returns null in views. How do I display/output the district name? I followed the instruction exactly based on Laravel documentation.

**DISTRICT TABLE**

[image]

**District Model**

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

**ADDRESS TABLE**

[image]

**Address Model**

```
public function district()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\District', 'district');
}
```

**View**

```
$getAddress = App\Address::all();

foreach($getAddress as $add)
{
   Address name: {{ $add->address_name }}
   District name : {{ $add->district['district_name'] }} //this returns null, WHY?
}
```

Comment: Referring to your provided tables the method `address` in `District Model` should return a `hasMany` relationship instead of `hasOne`. To get name of the `district` you should go fine with `{{ $add->district->district_name }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead you should get all value in one stroke by using `with`

```
$getAddress = App\Address::with('district')->all();
```

And get value as

```
{{ $add->district->district_name }}
```

Comment: got this error...caught ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$district_name

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object id i added [0]

Comment: brb try using `with`

Comment: After I modified my codes and use your solution, it works! Thank you so much. By using `with`, we can only call the model function? Just wanna kill my curiosity :)

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

```
<php $getAddress = App\Address::with('district')->get(); ?>

@foreach($getAddress as $add)

   Address name: {{ $add->address_name }}

   @foreach($add->district as $districrt)
    District name : {{ $districrt->district_name }} 
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```